# Proof: number of bits in the product of two binary numbers.

Tags: proof-writing, arithmetic, computer-science, binary

[Related question on StackOverflow without any proof/intuition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32721080/binary-multiplication-how-many-bits-is-a-product).

We have two numbers in binary: one with $n$ digits and another with $m$ digits. I know the general algorithm for multiplying two numbers together by longhand and understand why it works.

What I don't understand is how I can prove that the number of digits in such a product is in the range $[max(m,n), m+n]$.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You can do better than that: the product of two such positive integers will have either $m+n-1$ or $m+n$ binary digits.  And it is not restricted to binary: the equivalent statement is true in other bases including decimal

Hint:

- A positive integer has  $n$ base-$b$ digits and most significant digit non-zero if and only if it is in the interval $[b^{n-1},b^{n}-1]$
- $b^{m-1}\times b ^{n-1} = b^{m+n-2}$
- $(b^{m}-1) \times (b^{n}-1) \lt b^{m+n}$

Comment: Hmm, this is a bit confusing for me. I wonder if it has anything to do with the fact that $2^n * 2^m = 2^{n+m}$?

Comment: @AleksandrH - the second and third hints have a lot to do with $2^n \times 2^m = 2^{n+m}$